# Lua: Concatenating table values into string

Tags: lua, syntax-error, string-concatenation, lua-table

I want to put into a string randomly generated values using Lua. However, I keep getting an error.

```
   function main()

   times = 0

   while times < 10 do


        ValueOne = {"1","2","3","4","5"}
        ValueTwo = {"1","2","3","4","5"}

        aval = math.random(1,#ValueOne)
        bval = math.random(1,#ValueTwo)

        a = ValueOne[aval]
        b = ValueTwo[bval]

        print ("Generated Values: " ..a.." "..b)

        times = times + 1

    end

    end
    main()
```

I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...Eclipse\Lua\workspace\My_Project\src\main.lua:13: attempt to concatenate global 'b' (a nil value)
at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
at org.eclipse.koneki.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:122)
at org.eclipse.koneki.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:137)
```

This means that for some reason variable 'b' can't be concatenated. I'm probably doing something wrong. Please help.

Comment: Your `objects[7]` is nil.  Nil value cannot be concatenated.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I put in the wrong code snippet for that part. I've fixed it and it still comes with the same error.

Comment: Now it [works fine](http://ideone.com/RzjmUJ).